# Does EntityFramework allow you to map a single model to multiple tables?

Tags: entity-framework

My project will allow users to create and work on multiple projects, so most of my tables will accordingly have a **ProjectID** column.

However one of those tables, let's call it *ProjectData* will become very large very quickly, as each project can have hundreds of thousands of rows. To me it makes more sense to have a table for each Project, thus  001Data, 002Data, etc.

Does EntityFramework allow for such single model -> multiple table mappings?  Perhaps it would be better to have separate databases for each project, but that too provides its own set of challenges.

Comment: Even millions of rows is not a problem for a mature RDBMS. Scattering identical data over many tables is a disaster, and unnecessary.

Comment: The data won't be identical.  The desire would be to partition data.

Comment: I mean identically shaped data.